# using powershell like awk to get the console user

Tags: powershell, awk

I basically want to use powershell and get the console user like

"query session | findstr console | awk '{print $2}'"

but not using awk, but I can't get it to work.

```
$out = query session | findstr console # good
$consoleuser = $out.split('\s+')[1]    # doesn't work
```

$out looks something like:

```
>console           joe                       2  Active
```

$consoleuser ends up being:

```
ole           joe                       2  Active
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have suggested try the following

```
$out = query session | findstr console
$consoleuser = $($out -split('\s+'))[1]
```

Or you could try

```
$consoleuser = $ENV:username
```

Comment: ++ for the `$env:USERNAME` tip; note that there's no need for `$(...)`, the subexpression operator, when simple parentheses (`(...)`) will do; also, while using _method_-invocation syntax (`-split(…)`) with the `-split`  _operator_ happens to work in this case,
it is best avoided. Thus:  `$consoleuser = ($out -split '\s+')[1]`

Comment: Thanks for both of the suggestions, I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 3):

`.Split()` is a .Net string method, it doesn't use regexes. `-split` is the PowerShell operator and uses regexes.

And calling out to `findstr` is usable, but there's no need to leave PS to use it. e.g.

```
$out = query session | Where {$_ -match 'console'}
$consoleuser = ($out -split '\s+')[1]

((query session) -match 'console' -split '\s+')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [TessellatingHeckler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40250565/45375) with a further **optimization** (but note that [armorall171's helpful recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40250752/45375) to simply use `$env:USERNAME` may be all you need):

```
(-split ((query session) -match '^>console'))[1]
```

<sup>Output from external command `query session` is returned as an *array* of strings by PowerShell, and the `-match` operator filters that array down to only the matching elements (just 1 line in this case).</sup>

The **`-split` operator has a *unary* form** whose behavior is **similar to `awk`'s default field-parsing behavior**:

It splits the input into array elements by runs of whitespace, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace.

Example:

```
> -split "  ab  `t  `t    cde `n `n efgh       "
ab
cde
efgh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
($out -Split '\s+')[1]
```

More useful stuff [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/the-regular-expression-regex-in-powershell/)